# Could anybody check my SQL code using SET, SELECT and CAST all at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import some csv files into a table (on phpmyadmin). The problem is that the import wasn't really correct (the date wasn't showing, my values either (they showed correctly when the type was a VARCHAR) etc) so I thought about converting my values to the right type during my import. When I tried it for my date it worked using only the code below at the end :

```
SET Date = STR_TO_DATE (@dte, '%m.%d.%Y')
SQL;
```

But when I wanted to convert my values into a float or a decimal or whatever, it didn't work. It always says 'Syntax error or access violation' ( and I guess it starts from = ( Select CAST(@tot AS decimal(10,2))  etc ).

Do you have any suggestions please? 
The request

```
Select CAST(@tot AS decimal(10,2)) 
            from `bss_154`)
```

normally works on mySQL.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here is my code :

```
$sql=<<<SQL
    LOAD DATA INFILE '{$filename}' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE nsui.bss_154 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (@dte, `BSC_Name`, `Segment_Name`, `SEGMENT`, `UP_QUAL`, `UP_LEVEL`, 
    `DOWN_QUAL`, `DOWN_LEV`, `DISTANCE`, `MSC_INVOC`, `INTFER_UP`, 
    `INTFER_DWN`, `UMBR`, `PBDGT`, `OMC`, `DIR_RETRY`, `PRE_EMPTION`, 
    `FIELD_DROP`, `LOW_DISTANCE`, `BAD_CI`, `GOOD_CI`, `HO_DUE_SLOW_MOV_MS`, 
    `HO_DUE_MS_SLOW_SPEED`, `HO_DUE_MS_HIGH_SPEED`, 
    `HO_ATT_DUE_SWITCH_CIRC_POOL`, `HO_ATT_DUE_ERFD`, 
    `HO_ATT_DUE_TO_BSC_CONTR_TRHO`, `HO_ATT_DUE_TO_DADLB`, 
    `HO_ATT_DUE_TO_GPRS`, `HO_ATT_DUE_TO_HSCSD`, `HO_ATT_DUE_BAD_SUPER_RXLEV`, 
    `HO_ATT_DUE_GOOD_REGULAR_RXLEV`, `HO_ATT_DUE_DIRECT_ACCESS`, 
    `HO_ATTEMPT_INTERBAND_DUE_LEVEL`, `HO_ATTEMPT_DUE_TO_ISHO`, 
    `HO_ATT_DUE_INTERSYS_DIRECT_ACC`, `HO_ATT_FOR_AMR_TO_HR`, 
    `HO_ATT_FOR_AMR_TO_FR`, `HO_ATT_INTER_BAND_SDCCH`, 
    `HO_ATT_INTER_BAND_TCH`, `HO_ATT_INTER_BTS_TYPE_SDCCH`, 
    `HO_ATT_INTER_BTS_TYPE_TCH`, @tot) 
    SET Date = STR_TO_DATE (@dte, '%m.%d.%Y'),   
        Hoattempts_outgoing_and_intra-cell = (
            Select CAST(@tot AS decimal(10,2)) 
            from `bss_154`)
SQL;
```

Comment: your `hoattempts...` sub-select is selecting from the same table you're trying to insert into, which is a no-no. can't just do `hoat...=cast(...)`?

Comment: Yes, @MarcB I thought about that too. But hoat...=cast(...) isn't working. So I don't really see how am I supposed to write it... ?!

Comment: remove the `from bss_154` bit, then. sincey ou're selecting from a `@variable`, there's no point in selecting that variable from a table.

Comment: Thank you @MarcB but it's not working either

Answer (score 0):

Also, perhaps you want to create the proper data types (VARCHAR) in the table definition first, then import the data that you can, and then create another script that imports and fixes the field data that's left over using the proper FORMAT and CAST statement syntaxes:

FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

With some code like:

CAST(FORMAT(@tot, 'N', 'en-us') as varchar) As SOME_TOTAL

Comment: Thank you @DJay for your answer. I've tried something like : 
SET  Date = STR_TO_DATE (@dte, '%m.%d.%Y'),    
   `Hoattempts_outgoing_and_intra-cell` = 
   FORMAT(CAST(@tot AS decimal(10,0)), 'N', 'en-us') 
And it imported my files. I still have the same problem though which means that, for example, for 17 325 I'd get 999. Do you have any idea why or how to fix this? 
Thank you again